# How to change styling of jquery text()?

Tags: jquery, css

Suppose I have:

`<span id="spanny"><strong>some default text</strong></span>`

I get: **some default text**

Then I call:

```
$("#spanny").text("<strong>new text</strong>");
```

I get:

```
<strong>new text</strong>
```

What I wanted:

**new text**

How can I style the text to have the STRONG attr?

Comment: You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button, there's no need to add spaces to your code. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `html` instead of `text`:

```
$("#spanny").html("<strong>new text</strong>");
```

[`html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) is used to set HTML contents, whereas [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2) will escape the string.